# Can deleting the Git stash conceivably delete folders in the working directory?

Tags: git, macos, delete-file, git-stash

I recently deleted the many-months-old stash of a Git project I hadn't worked on for a few months. Without reviewing it, I know m-) Upon compiling the project about 30min later, several folders and file were missing. Pretty surely I didn't accidentally delete those through the Finder (they weren't in the Trash). After a restore from Time Machine, all worked out fine.

However, I'm left wondering whether there is any conceivable scenario in which files and folders in the working directory, were somehow attached to the old stash?

Answer (score 2):

No, `git stash drop` and `git stash clear` will not touch the working directory.

To figure out what went wrong, I'd suggest you look through your shell command history (by typing `history`) to see if there's anything else you might have done which could have deleted those directories.

Another possibility is that part of the compilation process deleted those directories.

Comment: OK, thanks for confirming. Still a strange incident... The other advice are unfortunately not applicable since I use the Terminal in that project only for executing the `make`, which was for LaTeX & pandoc and didn't contain any commands affecting the missing folders.